# Intel XDK build from Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm developing a Cordova hybrid app with only Android platform. I have modified AndroidManifest (inside `/platforms/android/` directory) and other some stuff (one of these modifications is change the `android:name` of `application` tag in manifest).

Now, if I build the project locally by:

`cordova build android`

everything is working fine. But when I build using Intel XDK (with android-crosswalk build), my modifications in AndroidManifest and other files are ignored. It seems that Intel XDK's build is deleting the `platforms` directory and re-creating it.

In that case, is there a way to keep intact this directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to do that with the XDK build.  You can provide some configuration options in the `intelxdk.config.*.xml` but I think that's the extent of build customization for now.

Comment: you can edit the plugin.xml of a plugin you have, and add there https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/general (Is it possible to modify the Android Manifest with the Intel XDK?)